# Read an XML file and show nodes in a combobox

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read an XML file which I want to make for my mom. So basically this is what I want to do:

A combobox which will show all the Name in the XML.

XML I wrote

```html
<Locatons.xml>
  <Name>ee</Name>
  <X>ere</X>
  <Y>erer</Y>
  <Z>re</Z>
  <Name>ee</Name>
  <X>eore</X>
  <Y>erer</Y>
  <Z>re</Z>
  <Name>878</Name>
  <X>8</X>
  <Y>4</Y>
  <Z>0</Z>
</Locatons.xml>
```

C# Code i Wrote To Add To Xml file

```html
        xDoc.Load(path);
        XmlNode name = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
        XmlNode x = xDoc.CreateElement("X");
        XmlNode y = xDoc.CreateElement("Y");
        XmlNode z = xDoc.CreateElement("Z");

        name.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
        x.InnerText = textBox2.Text;
        y.InnerText = textBox3.Text;
        z.InnerText = textBox4.Text;
        xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(name);
        xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(x);
        xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(y);
        xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(z);
        xDoc.Save(path);
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Or maybe googled?

Comment: i tryed all but the one i like best is the one Mad Sorcerer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this might help you..!
 using this name space : **using System.Xml.Linq;**

```
 List<String> nameList = new List<String>();
            var NAME= XElement.Parse(xml);

           if (NAME.Attribute("Name") != null)
        {
            nameList.Add(NAME.Attribute("Name").Value);
        }
```

give that dropdown datasource as nameList .

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var str = @"
<Locatons.xml>
  <Name>ee</Name>
  <X>ere</X>
  <Y>erer</Y>
  <Z>re</Z>
  <Name>ee</Name>
  <X>eore</X>
  <Y>erer</Y>
  <Z>re</Z>
  <Name>878</Name>
  <X>8</X>
  <Y>4</Y>
  <Z>0</Z>
</Locatons.xml>";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
var output = new List<string>();
foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants("Name"))
{
    output.Add(element.Value.ToString());
}
```

This will add them all to a `List` and from there you can populate the combobox.

Comment: thanks. but that add all so the combo and i only want to add <Name?

Comment: Thaks, sorry if you dont understood, i am from argentina i am 13 yars old i don kown how to speak enlish verry wel.

Answer (score 0):

How to get names from the file:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("Locations.xml");
var names = document.Root.XPathSelectElements("/*/Name").Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();
```

How to add tems to a combobox (assuming you are using WindowsForms), named NameBox for instance

```
NameBox.Items.AddRange(names);
```

don't forget

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```